# Updating session variables without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using modal to display form. I want to validate form and show possible errors after clicking submit button. I don't want to close my modal after validation so I decided to use Ajax. Here is my code:

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="offer-form" id="offer-form" action="offers.php" method="post">
                <label for="name-input">Name</label><br>
                <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION["name-error"])) {
                        echo "<p>".$_SESSION["name-error"]."</p>";
                        unset($_SESSION['name-error']);
                    } 
                ?>
                <input type="text" id="name-input" name="name"><br>

                <input type="submit" id="submit-input" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#offer-form").submit(function(e){    
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data: $("#offer-form").serialize(),
            url : 'validate.php',
            success : function(data){

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["name-error"] = "Error";
?>
```

The problem is that I have to refresh website to see error being displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is that your validation.php file where you are creating session ?

Comment: I'm using session_start() in both files.

Comment: @Hey joe u just set the session variable right and but in the ajax response  you have to set the content by javascript to see the message other vise php will do it work on page refresh

Answer (score 0):

return the value of the session to your ajax and using jquery append the error to the page:

Add the following to your success function

```
success : function(data){
        $('label[for="name-input"]').html('</br>'+data.message)
            }
```

in your php

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$_SESSION["name-error"] = "Error";
echo json_encode(["message"=>$_SESSION["name-error"]]);
?
```

Comment: Now I'm getting "undefined" instead of my error message.

Answer (score 0):

Display the error with JQUERY... If you want PHP to process your $_SESSION you will need to reload the page (because PHP in on the server side).

Do an echo in your PHP file and catch the data in your success function

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["name-error"] = "Error";
echo "ERROR";


success : function(data){
    if(data = "Error")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validation.php file

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["name-error"] = "Error";

  $error = array('error' => $_SESSION["name-error"]);
  echo json_encode($error);
```

Your Html

```
 <label for="name-input">Name</label><br>
            <p class='sessionError'></p>
```

Your ajax success funcion

```
        success : function(data){
         $('.sessionError').text(data.error);
            }
```